# Thinking about Neural Networks

Tags: r, neural-networks, missing-data

I am confused about the output I am getting for a neural network analysis.

What I am trying to do is take in the features from features.csv and use them to create a neural network to predict the variable `Murder.per.100.000`. The first column is a label for each observation so I exclude that. The problem I am having is that `preds` is a vector of `NA`. Some of my features are sparse. I assume I am not dealing with missing values correctly. How should I fix that? When I limit it to non-sparse features, `preds` is made up of all the same value somewhere near 1 which doesn't seem right either.

```
library('nnet')
dat          = read.table("features.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)
  # remove observation label
dat          = dat[ ,-c(1)]
nData        = dim( dat )[1]
trainInd     = sample( (1:nData), 300 )
  # create the training data:
trainData    = dat[ trainInd, ]
  # create the test and validation dataset:
notTrainData = dat[ -trainInd, ]
nData        = dim( notTrainData )[1]

valInd   = sample( (1:nData), nData/2 )
testData = notTrainData[-valInd,]
valData  = notTrainData[valInd,]
net      = nnet(Murder.per.100.000 ~ ., data=trainData, size=5, rang=.1, 
                decay=5e-4, maxit=200, na.action=na.exclude)
preds    = predict(object=net, newdata=valData)
```

Comment: Is this a question about the software `nnet`, neural networks, or how to deal with missing values of data? Debugging your R code is off-topic, but understanding missing data and neural networks are on-topic here. When you searched our archives for information about missing data methods and neural networks, in what way did previous answers not address your concerns?

Answer (score 1):

If there are missing values in your data, one approach is to perform a weighted probabilistic assignment from the values of the features that are there. So, if one column is "TimeOfDay", say, and eight rows have it as "Day" and two rows have it as "Night", then for each missing TimeOfDay value, assign it to "Day" 80% of the time and "Night" the other 20%. Of course, this may not be a great or meaningful approach; it depends on your situation.

If you need to repeat the creation/manipulation process, don't forget to `set.seed(x)` prior to manipulating your data, where `x` is a value of your choosing.